# How to restrict ajax call on every page in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am using Laravel 5.2 there are some of ajax call which are calls on every page. Now I want to ajax call required pages only.

My Routes

```
Route::auth();    
Route::get('/', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('users/client', 'ClientController@showClients');
Route::get('users/client/add', 'ClientController@addClient');
Route::get('dash/manage_graph', 'BoardController@showPowerManage');
// My ajax call 
Route::get('dash/manage_chart/chart/{request}', 'DashboardController@powerChart');
Route::get('dash/manage/chart/{request}', 'DashboardController@powerChart');
```

My data.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON('dash/manage_chart/chart/' + request, function (data) {
        $('#dg_hours').html(data);
    });
$.getJSON('dash/manage/chart' + request, function (data) {
        $('#dg_sec').html(data);
    });
});
```

Above is my routes. In my routes I am not using any Middleware for this. Now I am facing problem is my ajax call load on every page. Because of loading ajax my single page load time is more than 50 seconds. Now I don't know how to handle this. Please suggest me.

Comment: So your `DashboardController@powerChart` gets executed on every page? That is definetely strange, as it should only fire over at `dash/manage_chart/chart/{request}` and `dash/manage/chart/{request}`

Comment: @Adrenaxus  when my common js file load at that time ajax gets executed and dash/manage_chart/chart/{request} gets called

Comment: Your route file is fine. It seems like your problem is in on the Javascript side where every ajax call is made. Could  you post your Javascript file ?

Comment: Steve is right, the problem is probably somewhere in the .js where the ajax call gets executed every time.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard i update my question and added my .js file

Comment: Why not place the AJAX function in a separate file and only call the file on appropriate views?

Comment: @DanWhite i can not create new .js file due to company process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing the :

```
$.getJSON('dash/manage_chart/chart/' + request, function (data) {
   $('#dg_hours').html(data);
});
```

will **automatically** do the AJAX call whenever the HTML page is loaded. That's why your AJAX calls are always made.

Instead, you should do this :

```
var getPowerChart = function(request, data) {
    $.getJSON('dash/manage_chart/chart/' + request, function (data) {
        $('#dg_hours').html(data);
    });
}
```

And you should call `getPowerChart(request, data)` only when you need to do the corresponding AJAX call.

Additional note : since you can't create a new JS file, I guess the most simple way to do this is to add a data-page attribute to the `<body>` tag for example, and do this in Javascript :

```
var getPowerChart = function(request, data) {
    $.getJSON('dash/manage_chart/chart/' + request, function (data) {
        $('#dg_hours').html(data);
    });
}

if ($('body').data('page') == 'your-page') {
    var request = '...',
        data = '...';

    getPowerChart(request, data);
}
```